# algorithm2e with memoir class

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, memoir, algorithm2e

I use the class `memoir`, and include algorithms using the `algorithm2e` package. I would like to have in the toc an entry such as "List of Algorithms". I saw in the documentation of `algorithm2e` that I have to use the `dotocloa` option, however, when I use it with the memoir class, i got the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\listofalgorithms ->\tocfile 
                             {\listalgorithmcfname }{loa}
l.13 \listofalgorithms
```

A minimal document to reproduce the error is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[dotocloa]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \pagebreak
    \listofalgorithms
    Test
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Foo}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

If I change the document class to book, it works... Does anyone have an idea of what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get rid of the error is to define `\tocfile` command. A fixed version is given below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tocfile}[2]{%
 \begingroup%
 \chapter*{#1}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listalgorithmcfname}%
 \@starttoc{#2}%
 \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[dotocloa]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listofalgorithms

\chapter{Test}    

\blindtext

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Foo}
\end{algorithm}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The macro `\tocfile` inputs two arguments and sets the **List of Algorithms**. The following process is done by the macro:

1. The first argument is the heading to set as `\chapter*{}`.
2. Include the extension of file where the list of algorithms were written to auxiliary file named `\jobname.loa`.

Comment: Thanks to this I get rid of the error, however, It still not add an entry such as "List of Algorithms" in the table of contents. Any clue?

Comment: @Vince: I have updated the answer by adding  `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listalgorithmcfname}`. This will make what you are looking for.